# Objects disappearing when zoomin in and out

Tags: modeling

I want to make a 3D from a 2-dimensional floor plan in dxf. Size around 28 '(9m) X 54' (17m). I can see my plan when I open it but as soon as I want to zoom in or out I lose it because it immediately becomes too big or too small

How can I adjust the zoom according to the dimensions objects I create?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean but try this:

- Open the <kbd>N</kbd> panel menu.
- Go to the View tab.
- Set the Camera Clip Start value to a lower value than the current one.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! I try it with no success in the 3D workspace :-( When I try with a top view the zoom work properly